# How can I change the SMB server address my Music files are on?

Tags: itunes, smb

I store my iTunes library (now Music.app) on a Samba server. The server's DNS name has changed, but the volume/share name has not. The share is called `Media` and is mounted at `/Volumes/Media`

However, I am unable to sync my iPhone or play music in Music.app because it somehow still tried to connect to the old DNS name, even though from what I can tell the path names coded in the library don't contain the Samba server name. However when i try to sync my iPhone I get a message

> *There was a problem connecting to the server "*old.server.dns.name*"

This happens even if I first use *Go > Connect to server...* in the finder and connect to the server, so my music *is* available at the desired path `/Volumes/Media/music`...

I don't want to delete my library and re-import because I'll lose all my star ratings and play counts.

How can I resolve this? How can I update the Samba server path for the music in my Music.app library?

Comment: Don't remove the iTunes library just reset it to default (inside iTunes/Music) and then select the new location. That *should* do it. Let us know if it does not.

Comment: Did what Steve suggested work? You can also try to the change the "old" server connection in Keychain Access.

Comment: Sorry @SteveChambers I only just tried this, and to my surprise, it worked! I am surprised because "Music Media folder location" was actually still the default of `~/Music` but after making the change _with the new SMB server connected_ it re-linked all my music and I don't seem to have this problem anymore. I'll accept that as an answer if you post one!

Comment: sorry @Gummibando I have been busy with work and only just had a chance to check. Yes, Steve's suggestion seems to have worked. Attempting to sync my iPhone now but at least Music.app doesn't try to connect to the old server address anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough it is both more complicated and easier than it seems. Why? Because Apple wants you to do it their way, work-arounds sometimes fail and this is one of those times.

So, don't remove the iTunes library just reset it to default (inside Preferences > Music) mount your drive and then select the new location.

That should do it.

Comment: Sadly, while this appeared to work at first, I'm still getting prompted for the old server address. I may need to dump my entire library and start over... :(